# chrome remote desktop, headless install, black screen when accessed

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I've got an ubuntu 20.04 desktop that I'm trying to access with chrome remote desktop.  I had troubles installing via the gui so I went through the "headless" installation.  When I connect via the client machine, I'm asked to select a session, default or current ubuntu.  No matter which that I select I get a blank (black) screen with an x for a cursor.

Any ideas?
Wayne

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install an X Windows System desktop environment such as Xfce, Gnome, or Cinnamon.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#installing_an_x_windows_system_desktop_environment) refers to installation on a VM, but this has more or less been the process I've followed setting up Chrome Remote Desktop on my Linux machines.

Comment: This actually works `sudo apt install xfce4` (then choose it on first connect), but you will still get a new session. Also random fact - sometimes it happens to me that some things I open on remote physically, pop out on the phone X session x)

Comment: The link in the accepted answer is no longer working... Use this link instead: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#gnome
Just had the same problem and following these steps I got it working...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Debian having GNOME desktop set as default
I have resolved it by installing Chrome Remote Desktop from console (not from Chrome extentions), then start the machine at login view (without loggin) and log from Chrome Remote Desktop on GNOME:

First make sure that the desktop environment is GNOME (for my case), this can be verified by the command:

```
admin@debian:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
GNOME
```

**Install Chrome Remote Desktop**
I had to install Chrome Remote Desktop from console to avoid the problem "Unknown error has occurred" when adding the Debian machine to a Google account on Remote Desktop installed as extension

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb -P /tmp
apt install /tmp/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb

# Create the Chrome remote desktop configuration directory on the home directory when the TURN ON button is not available
mkdir ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop
```

Then I could Turn ON Chrome Remote Desktop the add successfully my machine on the tab "Remote access"

**Connect to Debian by Chrome Remote Desktop**

I had to restart the machine without login as shown bellow:

[image: Start Debian Machine without login]

Then connect to Debian machine from another machine and select GNOME desktop